# JSON.parse() no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

estoy haciendo una web con *JavaScript* y *PHP*. La pagina web a través de **javascript** y **jQuery** hace una petición **Ajax** a un archivo **PHP** que devuelve un **JSON** en forma de **string**. El problema es que cuando **JavaScript** convierte en **JSON** el **string** no me da error pero si hago un **console.log()** de el **JSON** ya convertido aparece como **string** en la consola. Aqui dejo el codigo:

**`PHP`**

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
if ($_POST['sesion'] != '') {
  $buscar = $_POST['sesion'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id='$buscar'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connUsuarios, $sql);
  if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $json[] = array(
        "respuesta" => "1",
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "nombre" => $row['nombre'],
        "usuario" => $row['usuario'],
        "correo" => $row['correo'],
        "password" => $row['password'],
        "estado" => $row['estado'],
        "registro" => $row['registro']
      );
    }
  } else {
    $json[] = array(
      "respuesta" => "0"
    );
  }
} else {
  $json[] = array(
    "respuesta" => "0"
  );
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
?>
```

**`JavaScript`**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'server/connect.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      sesion: window.getCookie('sesion')
    },
    success: function(response) {
      let dataSesion = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
      if (dataSesion[0]['respuesta'] == "1") {
        sesion = {
          active: true,
          id: dataSesion[0]['id'],
          name: dataSesion[0]['nombre'],
          user: dataSesion[0]['usuario'],
          mail: dataSesion[0]['correo'],
          password: dataSesion[0]['password'],
          status: dataSesion[0]['estado'],
          registerTime: dataSesion[0]['registro']
        }
      } else if (dataSesion[0]['respuesta'] == "0") {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('Ha ocurrido un error');
        document.write('<a href="login.php">Clic</a>');
        window.stop();
      } else {
        console.log(dataSesion)
      }
    }
  });
```

He intentado ya varias veces arreglarlo pero no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los parámetros de ajax es dataType. Con él le dices en qué formato estás recibiendo la respuesta y actuará en consecuencia. Añade lo siguiente

```
dataType: 'json',
```

en cualquier parte, por ejemplo debajo de type: 'json', y antes de data: ...
De esa manera, no necesitas usar

```
let dataSesion = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
```

La variable response será directamente un objeto json que podrás usar como quieras:

```
console.log("El nombre es: "+response.nombre);
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó. No sabia que existia dataType.

Comment: si te funciona, marca la respuesta útil como aceptada para que los buscadores puedan indexar esta solución y ayudar a otra gente